# I can't seem to clear out my localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I can't seem to get my localStorage to clear out

I have two seperate JS files, one is called StorageBin and the other is just called JAS2.

This is my code in the StorageBin

```
function MyStorage() { };
MyStorage.Keys = {
    MyNewObject:""
};

MyStorage.Keys = function (value) {
    localStorage.setItem(this.Keys.MyNewObject, JSON.stringify(value))
    return value;
};
```

in the JAS2 file is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myObject = {
        Name: "John",
        LastName: "Doe"
    }

    MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject = myObject;

    var hereItIs = MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject;

    console.log(hereItIs.LastName + ", " + hereItIs.Name);


    $('#btn').click(function () {

        //localStorage.removeItem("MyNewObject");
        //localStorage.removeItem("MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject");
        //window.localStorage.clear();
        //window.localStorage.removeItem("MyNewObject");

    });

    $('#btn2').click(function () {
        var hereItIs = MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject;

        console.log(hereItIs.LastName + ", " + hereItIs.Name);
    });


});
```

everything you see commented out in the btn click event is everything I have tried. None have worked, I know this because of my btn2 click event.

Where have I went wrong?

Comment: Where are you storing anything in the local storage to begin with?

Comment: @Xufox, the first code block that I showed..in the localStorage.setItem

Comment: But you aren’t calling that function anywhere.

Comment: What is (are) the expected key–value pair(s) that you want to save in the local storage?

Comment: @Xufox, the code works...MyNewObject is the key and I am passing in a JavaScript object. The function that you are talking about is MyStorage, this is used to pass the k/v into storage and also to read it from storage. The question isnt 'why can't i get localStorage to work', its 'I can't get my localStorage to clear'.

Comment: I wasn’t talking about the `MyStorage` function. I was talking about the `MyStorage.Keys` function which contains the `setItem` call. You didn’t show the code where you call something like `MyStorage.Keys("someValue")` to store an entry. There are lots of problems with your code, so I wouldn’t consider it “working”.

Comment: Also, when you say `MyNewObject` is the key, you mean the literal string `"MyNewObject"`, right?

Comment: You say there is lots of problems with my code and that you wouldn't consider it working. What are the problems with my code and if you haven't ran it then how can you not consider it to be working? Am I not putting anything into localStorage? I am not a Javascript developer, so I may not being doing it by the book and if you could point out all the problems then I would appreciate that so I don't keep making the same mistakes

Comment: How do you know I didn’t run this code? I’m currently preparing an answer to this question, explaining the important problems.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137173/discussion-between-chris-and-xufox).

Comment: Alright, I posted an answer. I’m still not exactly sure, what your final code should look like, though, because the whole `MyStorage` structure is a bit confusing. I’ve pointed out the basic ways to set the entry correctly and delete it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

You’re setting an entry with an *object* as a key, rather than a *string*. The resulting key name will be `"[object Object]"`, so you can’t access or delete it with `"MyNewObject"` or `"MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject"`.

---

First problem I noticed: `MyStorage.Keys` can’t be an object and a function simultaneously. So this code doesn’t make much sense:

```
MyStorage.Keys = { // This object will be lost shortly.
    MyNewObject: ""
};

MyStorage.Keys = function(value){
    localStorage.setItem(this.Keys.MyNewObject, JSON.stringify(value))
    return value;
};
```

The first assignment can be removed.

Of course, a new `MyNewObject` property will exist after this line:

```
MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject = myObject;
```

In the saving function (`MyStorage.Keys`), you’re setting a `LocalStorage` entry with the key `this.Keys.MyNewObject`. It refers to `myObject`, which is an object. This also doesn’t make sense, because `setItem` expects a *string* as the first argument, not an object. The argument will therefore be cast to a string and result in `[object Object]`.

---

It appears, however, that you want to access your `LocalStorage` entry with either `"MyNewObject"` or `"MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject"`. So just set it with one of these lines instead:

```
localStorage.setItem("MyNewObject", JSON.stringify(value));
```

```
localStorage.setItem("MyStorage.Keys.MyNewObject", JSON.stringify(value));
```

Then one of your two first attempts or the last one will work.

If you want the key to be `{Name:"John",LastName:"Doe"}`, use

```
localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify(this.Keys.MyNewObject), JSON.stringify(value));
```

If you want the key to be `Doe, John`, use

```
localStorage.setItem(hereItIs.LastName + ", " + hereItIs.Name, JSON.stringify(value));
```

In any case, if you want to remove those entries, you need to generate its key the same way.

`localStorage.clear();` should also clear everything from local storage. I can’t reproduce it not working.

---

### Debugging

You can debug the Local Storage by using the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and going to the `Storage` tab (you may need to enable it in the dev tools settings). There you will see which keys and values are saved.

---

### Further examples

[`Storage` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage)

#### Setting an entry

```
localStorage.setItem("MyNewObject", JSON.stringify(value));
```

#### Getting that entry

```
localStorage.getItem("MyNewObject");
```

#### Deleting that entry

```
localStorage.removeItem("MyNewObject");
```

Comment: After going over your answer and doing a comparison, I realized that my code wasn't placing anything in storage. Thanks to your answer I now have fixed all of my code and now things are getting into storage. Thank you for the explanation on why my code was wrong. Now I am doing MyStorage.Keys(key, value) and placing it into storage and created a new function called MyStorage.Get(key) and getting the key from storage. Oh and I am glad you showed me how to check what is in localStorage in the developer tools